# adding ssh path with ssh-agent everytime after reboot

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh

Everytime when I reboot from server I need to use `eval ssh-agent -s` and /home/user/id_rsa_github to identify my self so that I could pull from github. Adding keys with `-K` flag ask me for authentication PIN which is unknown for me. How I can add keys perminently?

Comment: you may need tweak `.git/config` file so is `url = git@github.com...`, not `url = https://...github.com...`

Answer (score 0):

As commented, check first the URL you are actually using:

```
 cd /path/to/repo
 git remote -v
```

If this is an HTTPS URL, you can:

- either change it to an SSH one

  ```
    git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
  ```
- or modify your configuration to use ssh

  ```
    git config url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
  ```